# Reset nested uiscrollview zooms when scroll ends

Tags: uiscrollview, nested, zooming, reset

Nested uiscrolls in a larger uiscroll need to, when zoomed, reset zoom level when they are off screen. I am trying to reset all of them when the scrolling ends but no luck. Any ideas?

```
myScrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
myScrollview.pagingEnabled = YES;
myScrollview.scrollEnabled =YES;
myScrollview.clipsToBounds = NO;
myScrollview.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
myScrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
myScrollview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
myScrollview.delegate = self;

NSInteger viewcount=4;
NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"01.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"02.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"03.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"04.png"],nil];

for (int i = 0; i <viewcount; i++)
{
    CGFloat x = i * self.view.frame.size.width;

    subView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [subView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [subView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    subView.clipsToBounds = NO;    // default is NO, we want to restrict drawing within our scrollview
    subView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    aImageView = [[UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:[images objectAtIndex:i]];
    [self.aImageView setTag:viewcount];
    [subView addSubview:aImageView];
    [subView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(aImageView.frame.size.width, subView.frame.size.height)];
    subView.minimumZoomScale = 1;
    subView.maximumZoomScale = 3;
    subView.delegate = self;
    [subView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    subView.contentSize = aImageView.frame.size;
    [myScrollview addSubview:subView];
}

myScrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*viewcount,self.view.frame.size.height);


[self.view addSubview:myScrollview];
```

}

```
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
NSLog (@"test");
UIView * view = nil;
view = [subView viewWithTag:0];
//return view;
return [scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
```

}

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
NSLog(@"Did scroll");
[self resetImageZoom];
```

}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
=    NSLog(@"Did end decal");

```
[self resetImageZoom];
```

}

-(void)resetImageZoom {
    NSLog(@"Resetting any image zoom");

```
for(UIView *view in [myScrollview subviews]) {
    //if([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
    //[(UIScrollView*)view setZoomScale:1.0 animated:NO];
    //}
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That did it...

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
NSLog(@"Did end dece");
for (UIView *view in scrollView.subviews) {
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        [(UIScrollView*)view setZoomScale:1.0 animated:NO];
    }
}
```

}